# Efficient, automated way to re-encode a large number of videos?

Tags: video, encoding

I have a lot of videos, mostly 1080p, that I want to re-encode / compress. A lot of them are, like I said, 1080p - however, they're also very high bitrate (I believe), and are just otherwise encoded with quality, not size, in mind - and I want to change this.

I want to find a tool, or script, that lets me input a list of videos and have it decide what the best format, bitrate, etc. is for each of those videos to shrink the size (And resize to 720p) to a more manageable level.

Is there such a tool? I've found programs that work per video (Like Handbrake), but require you to set the settings of each video you want to encode, by hand - which is really tedious when you're talking about hundreds of videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try Handbrake Batch Encoder.

http://videoscripts.wordpress.com/downloads/

Comment: Does this handle 4:3 as well as 16:9 aspect ratios automatically?

Comment: There's a "--keep-display-aspect" switch, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I have brought it up on other questions before, but you want Adobe Media Encoder. What one can do with this software is add multiple videos to the queue, select all of them and change them to re-encode all to the same format, and then start the queue and let it do its magic. simple enough.

**EDIT!**
There is also an application called "adapter" which does the exact same thing but in a more simple manner, and its free, too. Here's a link to where one could download it; http://www.macroplant.com/adapter/